# Create table on every database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The way this database is setup (not my design) is that every user has their own database with many tables, so if a user ever decides to leave us we can just give them their DB and they have all of their data. The issue is, when I create a new form or feature I need to create a table in each one of these databases (50+) and it takes a huge amount of my time. Is there any way to create a table in each database?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following query, then execute the output. 
If the table already exists in the schema it will still run. However, if the table already exists and you want to redefine it, you can tune this statement to drop those table and recreate them.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.define table here') 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN 
    ('mysql', 'information_schema', 'performance_schema');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it programmatically using a programming language like PHP or Python.
Here's the pseudocode that would need to be implemented.

```
get array of user databases by selecting from information_schema
for each database:
  SQL : "create table if not exists <database>.tableName ..."
end for each
```